# URISyntaxException error with MailChimp

Tags: exception, mailchimp

I'm getting this type of error:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 8: https://us7";.api.mailchimp.com/1.3/?method=lists
```

Firstly, I've checked that my code it works in a simple project Maven 2 project. Later, I've moved my code in my application, but it doesn't work correctly !

Any ideas would be appreciated !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I'm using 1.3 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've solved my problem. The key I've written in a properties file, it was with double quotes and semi-colon.